# Kivy placing an image on a certain spot of dynamicly generated buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I want to place circular Images on the left side of each button that is created, just like on a messaging App. The Images are going to be to be sent via server. I already have code using PIL to make the images into a circle as well. I just don't know how to position them on the corner of each button.

The Python file of the App:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage


Builder.load_file('main.kv')

login_plz = Popup(title='Please login',
              content=Label(text='You need to login first'),
              size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
              auto_dismiss=True)


class Menu(BoxLayout):
    access_denied = BooleanProperty(True)


class ScreenLogIn(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def verify_credentials(self):
        popup = Popup(title='Try again',
                  content=Label(text='Wrong Email/Password'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                  auto_dismiss=True)

        try:
            if len(self.ids.login.text) > 20 or   len(self.ids.passw.text) > 32:
                popup.open()
            elif self.ids.login.text == "a" and self.ids.passw.text == "a":
                App.get_running_app().root.access_denied = False
                self.manager.current = "match"
            else:
                App.get_running_app().root.access_denied = True
                popup.open()
        except Exception as e:
            pass


class ScreenNearUsers(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):
        if App.get_running_app().root.access_denied is True:
            self.manager.current = 'login'
            login_plz.open()
        else:
            for i in xrange(101):
                button = Button(text="B_" + str(i))
                self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)


class ScreenMatch(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if App.get_running_app().root.access_denied is True:
            self.manager.current = 'login'
            login_plz.open()
        else:
            for i in range(10):
                src = "http://placehold.it/480x270.png&text=slide-%d&.png" % i
                image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False,opacity=1,size_hint=(1, 1.3),
                               pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}, border=True)
                self.ids.carousel.add_widget(image)


class ScreenChats(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if App.get_running_app().root.access_denied is True:
            self.manager.current = 'login'
            login_plz.open()
        else:
            for i in range(50):
                button = Button(text='Some_name')
                self.ids.chat_layout.add_widget(button)


class ScreenUserProfile(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if App.get_running_app().root.access_denied is True:
            self.manager.current = 'login'
            login_plz.open()
        else:
            pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_log_in = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_near_user = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_match = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_chats = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_user_profile = ObjectProperty(None)


class MenuApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Menu()

    def on_start(self):
        self.current_screen = 'login'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuApp().run()
```

This the the main Kv:

```
<Menu>:
    manager: screen_manager
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: action

    ActionBar:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        background_color: 0, 0, 1000, 10
        background_normal: ""
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                app_icon:""
                with_previous: False

                text:"    [b]Dhobiwala.com[/b]"

                markup:True
                font_size:"16dp"
            ActionButton:
                id: near_users
                size_hint: 1, 1
                height: self.texture_size[ 1 ]
                width: self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 40
                minimum_width: self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 60

               halign: "center"
               icon: 'icons/internet.png'
               disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
               on_press: root.manager.current = 'near_users'
           ActionButton:
               id: matching_bar
               size_hint: 1, 1

               height: self.texture_size[ 1 ]
               width: self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 40
               minimum_width: -self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 60
               halign: "center"
               text: "Matching"
               disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
               on_press: root.manager.current= 'match'
           ActionButton:
               id: chat
               size_hint: 1, 1

               height: self.texture_size[ 1 ]
               width: self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 40
               minimum_width: self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 60

               halign: "center"
               text: "chat"
               disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
               on_press: root.manager.current = 'chats'
           ActionButton:
               id: profile
               size_hint: 1, 1

               height: self.texture_size[ 1 ]
               width: self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 40
               minimum_width: self.texture_size[ 0 ] + 60

               halign: "center"
               text: "Profile"
               disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
               on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'
    Manager:
        id: screen_manager

<ScreenLogIn>:
    id: login_screen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 20, 20
        spacing: 50
        TextInput:
            id: login
            size_hint_y: None

            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            size_hint_y: None
            multiline: False
            password: True # hide password
        Button:
            text: "Log In"
            on_release: root.verify_credentials()

<ScreenNearUsers>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 0, 0
            padding: 0, 0


<ScreenMatch>:
    name: 'Carousel'
    fullscreen: True

    BoxLayout:
       size_hint_y: None
       height: '48dp'

       Button:
           text: 'last user'
           id: last_user

       Button:
            text: 'like'

       Button:
           text: 'super like'
           on_release: carousel.load_previous()

       Button:
           text: 'Dislike'
           on_release: carousel.load_next()

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'

    Carousel:
        id: carousel
        loop: last_user.state == 'down'


<ScreenChats>:

    ScrollView:        
        GridLayout:
            id: chat_layout
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols: 1
            row_default_height: '125dp'
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 0, 0
            padding: 0, 0


<ScreenUserProfile>:

    Button:
        text: "stuff4"

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    screen_log_in: screen_log_in
    screen_near_users: screen_near_users
    screen_match: screen_match
    screen_chats: screen_chats
    screen_user_profile: screen_user_profile

    ScreenLogIn:
        id: screen_log_in
        name: 'login'
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenNearUsers:
        id: screen_near_users
        name: 'near_users'
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenMatch:
        id: screen_match
        name: 'match'
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenChats:
        id: screen_chats
        name: 'chats'
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenUserProfile:
        id: screen_user_profile
        name: 'profile'
        manger: screen_manager
```

I am going to make the button transparent so I am not worried about the corners of the buttons showing outside of the circle images.

Picture with example of wanted position

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `background_normal` property of `Button`? You may need to do some even more complicated image manipulation, like making the image have the same aspect ratio as your `Button`, because the Button will stretch/shrink it to fit the `Button`. You might also need to make everything in the image transparent, except the area inside the circle.

Comment: How do I change the aspect ratio?

Comment: By that I mean that your circular image may need to actually be a rectangular image with width/length in the same ratio as your `Button`.

Comment: Ok thank you I understand what you mean now.

Comment: I have it where I can combine the transparent image and the circle image, but I can not get it to fit the button with out stretching very badly?

Comment: That's why you need to use an image that is as close to the size of your `Button` as you can get, or at least the same aspect ratio.